# Android TV app google maps marker isn't focusable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, android-tv

Can we add focus to Markers of Google maps for Android TV app? can we move to the Marker using TV remote.

Are there Google Maps Api dedicated to Android TV.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html) about how to handle hardware like TV.

> TV hardware is substantially different from other Android devices. TVs
>   do not include some of the hardware features found on other Android
>   devices, such as touch screens, cameras, and GPS receivers. TVs are
>   also completely dependent on secondary hardware devices. In order for
>   users to interact with TV apps, they must use a remote control or game
>   pad.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893246/is-it-possible-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-api-for-android-tv) also discuss how the user handled the Google Maps Geolocation API for Adroid TV.

So IP Address was used instead of Cell tower and Wifi access points. Because currently Geolocation is achievable using that options.

Comment: Hi, The document you shared it doesn't contain anything related to Maps handling. So, is it possible to handle Markers using remote controller?